# How do I force the light theme for a MAUI Windows application?

Tags: xaml, themes, maui

I would like to force the theme for a MAUI Windows app, for example for screenshot purposes. The `Shell` and `Application` Elements don't support the `RequestedTheme` property that can be used with WinUI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can force the theme by setting the `RequestedTheme` property in the App.xaml in the Platforms\Windows subfolder in the project:

```
<maui:MauiWinUIApplication
    x:Class="NetMaui.WinUI.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:maui="using:Microsoft.Maui"
    RequestedTheme="Light"
    xmlns:local="using:NetMaui.WinUI">

</maui:MauiWinUIApplication>
```

Comment: Is there a way to force light mode on Android (Maui app)? I've not designed a dark mode and just found the app doesn't display correctly in dark mode.

Comment: Lennart, what about android?

Comment: No idea, sorry. I don't use Maui regularly anymore.

Comment: @AhmedMohammedali to force light theme for your app on Android you can add the 2 lines to your App constructor: UserAppTheme = AppTheme.Light;
        AppCompatDelegate.DefaultNightMode = AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightNo;

Answer (score 3):

Android:

In MainApplication.cs add into constructor

```
AppCompatDelegate.DefaultNightMode = AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightNo;
```

iOS:

Add into Info.plist new key / value

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key> <!-- For light mode only -->
<string>Light</string>
```

NOTE:

For both platforms works also following
In App.xaml.cs (**project file**, **not** under Platforms\Windows) add into constructor

```
Application.Current.UserAppTheme = AppTheme.Light;
this.RequestedThemeChanged += (s, e) => { Application.Current.UserAppTheme = AppTheme.Light; };
```