# Current.UserAppTheme = AppTheme.Light Not working

Tags: maui

I want to force Light theme on my MAUI app, and according to Microsoft's documentation, my code is write, I need to have " Current.UserAppTheme = AppTheme.Light", but still app runs on dark theme.

I hace that line od code before my "MainPage = new AppShell". Tried putting it afterwards but still, no luck.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You should improve your question with all relevant details and show the code you're facing the issue with.

Comment: I recommend defining the colors you want to use, rather than relying on what is built-in. This will ensure colors are same on all platforms. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/theming and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/system-theme-changes.

Comment: Daniel, I understand what you are trying to do, but you are out of luck, fella. Here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10490. Also, even if you do what ToolmakerSteve tells you, you will still have issues with those controls. I say - try dealing with each platform separately. Google "FORCE light mode Xamarin". Or do what I do - play dead and wait for those bugs to get fixed.

Comment: @H.A.H. Indeed, there are some issues with this. However, the question is not concise enough. There are workarounds for some of the theming issues and many controls work just fine. The OP needs to clarify and improve the question nevertheless.

Comment: @ewerspej The question is more clear than it has to be. The documentation he is reading is this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/system-theme-changes#set-the-current-user-theme. I have not tested it recently, but my last attempt to make this work failed. And the only way I have found while exploring solutions was to deal with it, for each platform separately - this is something I try to avoid.

Comment: Do you still meet this issue? If so, what platform and API level you used? And what the MAUI version you used?  Besides you may refer to this thread:  [How do I force the light theme for a MAUI Windows application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70518665/how-do-i-force-the-light-theme-for-a-maui-windows-application).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have a repo that I can clone and try, that might be helpful. This video might help you out. Had a similar issue.
This code needs to go in your MainApplication.cs under Android platform folder.

```
AppCompatDelegate.DefaultNightMode = AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightNo;
```

https://youtu.be/7Rqq8LrdkO8

Comment: I am using .NET MAUI with .NET 8 and save same lines of code but when I am running on Android 11 device, it is throwing exception :  Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'no static method "Landroidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatDelegate;.setDefaultNightMode(I)V"'